# Multiplying Combinations Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I need a tiny bit of help with this code, Some background information: The user inputs a number, the code takes the number and outputs various combinations of numbers that multiply to it.

For example:

Input: 7
Output: (1,7)(7,1).

*But what really happens:
*
Input: 7
Output: (7,1)

**I want my code to reverse the numbers as well, so it makes can look like it has two combinations**

```
    
     var input= parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number larger than 1"));
     var arr = [];
            if(input <= 1) {
                 console.log("Goodbye!")
            }
   
        while(input > 0) {
         var arr = [];
         var input = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number larger than 1"));
   
         for (var i = 0; i < input; ++input) {
            var r = ((input / i) % 1 === 0) ? (input / i) : Infinity 
            if(isFinite(r)) {
                    arr.unshift(r + ", " + i)

           }
       }  
       console.log("The multiplicative combination(s) are: " + "(" + arr.join("), (") + "). ");
    }
```

**My code just need this tiny bit of problem fixed and the rest will be fine!**

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 infinite loop because you never change `i` and always increase `input`.
also in this line `for (var i = 0; i < input; ++input)` you never let `i` to be equal to the `input` so in your example (input=7) you can not have (7,1) as one of your answers. I think this is what you looking for:

```js
var input = 1;
while(input > 0) {
    input = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number larger than 1"));
    if(input > 1) {
        var arr = [];
    
        for (var i = 0; i <= input; ++i) {
            var r = ((input / i) % 1 === 0) ? (input / i) : Infinity 
            if(isFinite(r)) {
                arr.unshift(r + ", " + i)

            }
        }  
        console.log("The multiplicative combination(s) are: " + "(" + arr.join("), (") + "). ");
        continue;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Goodbye!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that I need the while loop until the user enters a negative number

Comment: @codingstudentwhoneedshelp Ok, I edited my answer. this should work.